# Как сделать сортировку в StringGrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, stringgrid

У меня есть вот такая таблица StringGrid:

[image: таблица]

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопок "сортировка по группе" и "сортировка по фамилии", к примеру, данные сортировались от А-Я по соответствующим столбцам?

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать простейшую пузырьковую сортировку:

```pascal
procedure TfmMain.SortGrid(Column: integer);
var
  i, j: integer;
  tmpRow: TStringList;
begin
  tmpRow:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i:=0 to StringGrid.RowCount-1 do
      for j:=i+1 to StringGrid.RowCount-1 do
        // сортируем по возрастанию.
        if AnsiCompareStr(StringGrid.Cells[Column, i], StringGrid.Cells[Column, j])>0 then
          begin
            tmpRow.Assign(StringGrid.Rows[i]);
            StringGrid.Rows[i]:=StringGrid.Rows[j];
            StringGrid.Rows[j]:=tmpRow;
          end;
  finally
    tmpRow.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: В Button написал такой текст: SgSort(StringGrid1, 1); 
Выдает ошибку : 'List index out of bounds (28)'

Comment: @Ник Это замечательно, но где в моем коде вы видите метод `SgSort`? Даже если это просто изменение имени предложенного мной метода - список параметров разный. Вывод - вы адаптировали код, представленный в ответе, под свои нужды. Это похвально, но я не могу знать, что именно вы изменили, поэтому сказать - где **у вас** в коде ошибка тоже не могу. List index out of bounds  в приведенном мной коде возникнуть не может - все данные выбираются в пределах валидного диапазона для `StringGrid`