# Как сортировать по двум столбцам в StringGrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
procedure GridSort(StrGrid: TStringGrid; NoColumn: Integer);
var
  Line, PosActual: Integer;
  Row: TStringList;
  Renglon :TStringList;
begin
  Renglon := TStringList.Create;
  Row := TStringList.Create;
  for Line := 0 to StrGrid.RowCount-1 do
  begin
    PosActual := Line;
    Row.Assign(StrGrid.Rows[PosActual]);
    while True do
    begin
      if (PosActual = 0) or
         (Row.Strings[NoColumn] >= StrGrid.Cells[NoColumn,PosActual-1])
        then break;
      StrGrid.Rows[PosActual] := StrGrid.Rows[PosActual-1];
      Dec(PosActual);
    end;
    if (Row.Strings[NoColumn] < StrGrid.Cells[NoColumn,PosActual])
      then StrGrid.Rows[PosActual].Assign(Row);
  end;
  Row.Free;
  Renglon.Free;
end;
```

Код выше сортирует один столбец путём `GridSort(StringGrid1, 1);`  И работает он так:
[image: Как работает сортировка]

Возможно модифицировать код, чтобы я выбрал в первом столбце ячейку "КСК12" (то есть любую, не по алфавитному порядку группу), и он вывел мне первыми строки с "КСК12" и фамилиями по алфавиту, а далее пошли другие группы. 
И как сделать, чтобы не затрагивал фиксированные строки?

Comment: Вкратце: да, возможно. Какие сложности у вас возникли с модификацией под несколько условий сортировки кода из ответа на предыдущий ваш вопрос, по сути - от этого вопроса почти не отличающийся? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/526491/192901

Comment: SgSort(StringGrid1, 1);
'List index out of bounds (28)'

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните свой вопрос необходимой информацией: 1. Ваш вариант кода, который должен выполнять поставленную в вопросе задачу. 2. Указание в этом коде места, где возникает ошибка. Текущий представленный код, мягко говоря, не особенно понятен и он не отражает вашей попытки решить задачу. И вдогонку - чем был плох код, предложенный в ответе на предыдущий вопрос?